# How to rotate camera view with glm?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to rotate my camera with the purpose of see an object rotating around my cam with a rotation Matrix that I develop the problem is that it doesn't works.

So I try with the glm::rotation matrix and put the values

> ```
> m_View = glm::rotate(m_View, a * glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
> ```

but it does not works either:

```cpp
void CCam::setView()
{

    Front = glm::normalize(Eye - At);
    Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Up, Front));
    up = glm::cross(Front, Right); // Up Verdadero


    m_View = glm::lookAt(
        Eye,    // Camera Position
        (Eye + Front),      // Where the camera looks
        up      // This is another way to say camera is not rotated 
    );


    newAt = glm::vec4(At, 1.0f);


    //m_View = m_View * GLMatrixRotationY(a);
    m_View = glm::rotate(m_View, a * glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

```
glm::mat4 CCam::GLMatrixRotationX(float Angle)
{
    matrizRotacionX = glm::mat4(
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, cos(Angle), -sin(Angle), 0,
        0, sin(Angle), cos(Angle), 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    );

    return matrizRotacionX;
}
```

I expect to see my mesh rotating around the camera but I only got the cam rotating around the mesh.